# Deserialize ushort[] filled with bits and bytes to custom object

Tags: c#, arrays, object, serialization, deserialization

I have an ushort[] with more than 450 members that is filled repeating 12 bool and 1 byte values like this:

[image]

I need to get Person objects from the array or get `ushort[]` from `List<Person>`, so basically I need to deserialize and serialize this `ushort[]`.

To parse it easily I thought maybe I can deserialize it to individual objects like this but gave up after it looked terrible:

```
class Person
{
    public bool Property0 { get; set; }
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
    public bool Property2 { get; set; }
    public bool Property3 { get; set; }
    public bool Property4 { get; set; }
    public bool Property5 { get; set; }
    public bool Property6 { get; set; }
    public bool Property7 { get; set; }
    public bool Property8 { get; set; }
    public bool Property9 { get; set; }
    public bool Property10 { get; set; }
    public bool Property11 { get; set; }
    public byte Property12 { get; set; }
}


private List<Person> Deserialize(ushort[] array)
{
    var personList = new List<Person>();
    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(array[i]);

        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            person1 = new Person();
            person1.Property0 = bitArray[0];
            person1.Property1 = bitArray[1];
            person1.Property2 = bitArray[2];
            person1.Property3 = bitArray[3];
            person1.Property4 = bitArray[4];
            person1.Property5 = bitArray[5];
            person1.Property6 = bitArray[6];
            person1.Property7 = bitArray[7];
            person1.Property8 = bitArray[8];
            person1.Property9 = bitArray[9];
            person1.Property10 = bitArray[10];
            person1.Property11 = bitArray[11];
        }

        if (i % 3 == 1)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
            bitArray.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
            person1.Property12 = bytes[0];
            
            personList.Add(person1);

            person2 = new Person();
            person2.Property0 = bitArray[0];
            person2.Property1 = bitArray[1];
            person2.Property2 = bitArray[2];
            person2.Property3 = bitArray[3];
            person2.Property4 = bitArray[4];
            person2.Property5 = bitArray[5];
            person2.Property6 = bitArray[6];
            person2.Property7 = bitArray[7];
        }

        if (i % 3 == 2)
        {
            person2.Property8 = bitArray[8];
            person2.Property9 = bitArray[9];
            person2.Property10 = bitArray[10];
            person2.Property11 = bitArray[11];

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
            bitArray.CopyTo(bytes, 5);
            person2.Property12 = bytes[0];

            personList.Add(person2);
        }
    }
    return personList;
}
```

How can I make this pretty?

I use attributes to serialize/deserialize json but libraries do the work, is there something like that for array deserialization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain better the `ushort[]` and the starting index part? Sorry but some pieces are missing in my opinion, even the code you show us does not tell us much about what you want to do.

Comment: The `BitArray` constructor overload used creates an instance filled with `false` values. Therefore, it makes no sense to create it and then copy `false` from it. Just fill in all the `person1` and `person2` properties with the values `false` and `0`.

Comment: I tried to simplify the question and remove unnecessary information from it, can you please check it again? Basically I just need to serialize/deserialize an ushort[] that is filled with 12 bit 1 byte values.

Comment: Again: `new BitArray(array[i])` creates empty bitArray filled with `false` values. You don't use ushort array values in your code.

Comment: I didn't say that my code works, when I searched I found BitArray and tried to write example method to show my intent and what I tried to solve my question. That code basically means that I just didn't ask a question in Stack Overflow without at least researching.

Comment: Show us `ushort[]` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to do such deserialization, I would use following approach as start and improve upon it.

First of all, I would update `Person` class to:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly BitArray booleanPropertyBits;
    private readonly byte bit16To23;
    
    public Person(byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3)
    {
        booleanPropertyBits = new BitArray(new byte[] { byte1, byte2 });
        bit16To23 = byte3;
    }

    public bool Property0 => booleanPropertyBits[0];
    public bool Property1 => booleanPropertyBits[1];
    public bool Property2 => booleanPropertyBits[2];
    public bool Property3 => booleanPropertyBits[3];
    public bool Property4 => booleanPropertyBits[4];
    public bool Property5 => booleanPropertyBits[5];
    public bool Property6 => booleanPropertyBits[6];
    public bool Property7 => booleanPropertyBits[7];
    public bool Property8 => booleanPropertyBits[8];
    public bool Property9 => booleanPropertyBits[9];
    public bool Property10 => booleanPropertyBits[10];
    public bool Property11 => booleanPropertyBits[11];
    public byte Property12 => bit16To23;
}
```

After that, I would have a helper class which would convert ushort[] in to byte[], like:

```
public static class ByteStream
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> From(ushort[] array)
    {
        foreach (var number in array)
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                yield return b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, I would use helper method to read values in following manner:

```
private List<Person> Deserialize(ushort[] array)
{
    var bytes = ByteStream.From(array).ToArray();
    var retVal = new List<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 3)
    {
        var person = new Person(bytes[i], bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2]);
        retVal.Add(person);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Not a complete solution but something to start and improve upon by adding validation checks and some performance tweaks.

Comment: @Caguryay did this help at all?